# Any bandwidth and performance limitation of Vnet-to-Vnet connection?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have two kind of services deployed on Azure, and they need communicate with each other. So far two options:
1. Put them in same Vnet
2. Put them in separate Vnet and create Vnet-to-Vnet connection between them.

My question is, is there any performance/bandwidth limitation on option 2 compared to option 1?

Answer (score 0):

I would say approach 1 is better in case you have less load in your vNet.

In Approach 2 the communication depends on below factors-
1. Whether the two vNets are in same region or not. If yes obviously you will face less latency.
2. Which vNet gateway you have selected- high performance vNet gateway provides faster speed over basic and standard.

Azure point to site vpn connections are reliable only  when the data to be transferred is not much ( < 1Tb ) and are in the same region.

Comment: Thanks your help! So even two VNET are in same region and I choose the high perf vNet gateway, option still bring some latency compared to option 1?

Comment: Check the bandwidth limits for a vnet2vnet vpn connection, depending on the gateway size, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways - if both VMs are in the same Vnet, chances are the bandwidth will be higher (and you don't have to pay for the gateways on both Vnets)

Comment: If you are planning to host that in separate VNET then use VNET peering, latency is higher in VPN VNET TO VNET traffic than VNET peering.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that with option 2 you will face egress data charges for traffic exiting the VNET.

If you're workloads are similar or are even in two separate tiers (web vs app vs data for example), you can segregate them via subnet and NSG. You don't need to separate out into different VNETs.

Comment: If the Vnets were in the same Zone there would not be data transfer charges.   I agree that this should probably be done with subsets and NSGs.